# how to convert latitude and longtitude to a current address in flutter, get time in and time out and time duration and store in firebase

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile-development

Im a flutter and noob, and having problems trying too convert latitude and longitude to a current address in flutter using geocoding and store in firebase/firestore in an app im trying to develop. The App stores latitude and longitude in firestore once the user .logs in and enables live loocation, the current latitude and longitude are displayed but the current address is yet to be displayed.

```
import 'dart:async';


import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:demo/model/user_model.dart';
import 'package:demo/screens/liveMap.dart';
import 'package:geocoding/geocoding.dart';
import 'package:demo/screens/login_screen.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


import 'package:location/location.dart' as loc;
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
  UserModel loggedInUser = UserModel();

  final loc.Location location = loc.Location();
  StreamSubscription<loc.LocationData>? _locationSubscription;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
   
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .doc(user!.uid)
        .get()
        .then((value) {
      this.loggedInUser = UserModel.fromMap(value.data());
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Welcome'),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                height: 130,
                child: Image.asset(
                  'assets/images/logo.png',
                  fit: BoxFit.contain,
                ),
              ),
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  _getLocation();
                },
                child: Text('Enable Live Location'),
              ),
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  _stopListening();
                },
                child: Text('Stop Live Location'),
              ),
              Expanded(
                  child: StreamBuilder(
                stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                    .collection('location')
                    .snapshots(),
                builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                  if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                    return Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    );
                  }
                  return ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: snapshot.data?.docs.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return ListTile(
                          title: Text(
                          snapshot.data!.docs[index]['name'].toString()),
                          subtitle: Row(
                            children: [
                              Text(snapshot.data!.docs[index]['latitude']
                                  .toString()),
                              SizedBox(width: 20),
                              Text(snapshot.data!.docs[index]['longitude']
                                  .toString()),
                            ],
                          ),
                          trailing: IconButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) =>
                                      LiveMap(snapshot.data!.docs[index].id)));
                            },
                            icon: Icon(Icons.directions),
                          ),
                        );
                      });
                },
              )),
              SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              Text(
                '${loggedInUser.name}',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54),
              ),
              Text(
                '${loggedInUser.email}',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 15,
              ),
              ActionChip(
                  label: Text('Logout'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    logout(context);
                  })
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> logout(BuildContext context) async {
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginScreen()));
  }

  Future<void> _getLocation() async {
    _locationSubscription = location.onLocationChanged.handleError((onError) {
      print(onError);
      _locationSubscription?.cancel();
      setState(() {
        _locationSubscription = null;
      });
    }).listen((loc.LocationData currentLocation) async {
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('location').doc('user1').set({
        
        'latitude': currentLocation.latitude,
        'longitude': currentLocation.longitude,
        'name': '${loggedInUser.name}',
        ''
      }, SetOptions(merge: true));
    });
  }


  _stopListening() {
    _locationSubscription?.cancel();
    setState(() {
      _locationSubscription = null;
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the address from latitude and longitude in flutter:

1.add geocodeing to pubspec.yaml using:

```
flutter pub add geocoding
```

2. import

   ```
   import 'package:geocoding/geocoding.dart';
   ```
3. use such function

   ```
   String _address = "";
   print_Address() async {
            List<Placemark> newPlace = await placemarkFromCoordinates(51.3468345, 6.8754743);
        Placemark placeMark  = newPlace[0];
        String? name = placeMark.name;
        String? subLocality = placeMark.subLocality;
        String? locality = placeMark.locality;
        String? administrativeArea = placeMark.administrativeArea;
        String? postalCode = placeMark.postalCode;
        String? country = placeMark.country;
        String address = "${name}, ${subLocality}, ${locality}, ${administrativeArea} ${postalCode}, ${country}";
        print(address); // do what you want with it
        _address = address;
     }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
dependencies:
  geocoding: ^2.0.1
```

---

Example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

import 'template/globals.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(BaseflowPluginExample());
}

/// A Flutter application demonstrating the functionality of this plugin
class BaseflowPluginExample extends StatelessWidget {
  /// [MaterialColor] to be used in the app [ThemeData]
  final MaterialColor themeMaterialColor =
      createMaterialColor(const Color.fromRGBO(48, 49, 60, 1));

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Baseflow $pluginName',
      theme: ThemeData(
        accentColor: Colors.white60,
        backgroundColor: const Color.fromRGBO(48, 49, 60, 0.8),
        buttonTheme: ButtonThemeData(
          buttonColor: themeMaterialColor.shade500,
          disabledColor: themeMaterialColor.withRed(200),
          splashColor: themeMaterialColor.shade50,
          textTheme: ButtonTextTheme.primary,
        ),
        bottomAppBarColor: const Color.fromRGBO(57, 58, 71, 1),
        hintColor: themeMaterialColor.shade500,
        primarySwatch: createMaterialColor(const Color.fromRGBO(48, 49, 60, 1)),
        textTheme: TextTheme(
          bodyText1: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontSize: 16,
            height: 1.3,
          ),
          bodyText2: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontSize: 18,
            height: 1.2,
          ),
          button: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          headline1: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontSize: 18,
          ),
        ),
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
        inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(
          fillColor: const Color.fromRGBO(37, 37, 37, 1),
          filled: true,
        ),
      ),
      home: AppHome(title: 'Baseflow $pluginName example app'),
    );
  }

  /// Creates a [MaterialColor] based on the supplied [Color]
  static MaterialColor createMaterialColor(Color color) {
    final strengths = <double>[.05];
    final swatch = <int, Color>{};
    final r = color.red, g = color.green, b = color.blue;

    for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
      strengths.add(0.1 * i);
    }
    for (var strength in strengths) {
      final ds = 0.5 - strength;
      swatch[(strength * 1000).round()] = Color.fromRGBO(
        r + ((ds < 0 ? r : (255 - r)) * ds).round(),
        g + ((ds < 0 ? g : (255 - g)) * ds).round(),
        b + ((ds < 0 ? b : (255 - b)) * ds).round(),
        1,
      );
    }
    return MaterialColor(color.value, swatch);
  }
}

/// A Flutter example demonstrating how the [pluginName] plugin could be used
class AppHome extends StatefulWidget {
  /// Constructs the [AppHome] class
  AppHome({required this.title});

  /// The [title] of the application, which is shown in the application's
  /// title bar.
  final String title;

  @override
  _AppHomeState createState() => _AppHomeState();
}

class _AppHomeState extends State<AppHome> {
  final _pageController = PageController(initialPage: 0);
  var _currentPage = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).bottomAppBarColor,
        title: Center(
          child: Image.asset(
            'res/images/baseflow_logo_def_light-02.png',
            width: 140,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
      body: PageView(
        controller: _pageController,
        children: pages,
        onPageChanged: (page) {
          setState(() {
            _currentPage = page;
          });
        },
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: _bottomAppBar(),
    );
  }

  BottomAppBar _bottomAppBar() {
    return BottomAppBar(
      elevation: 5,
      color: Theme.of(context).bottomAppBarColor,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: List.unmodifiable(() sync* {
          for (var i = 0; i < pages.length; i++) {
            yield Expanded(
              child: IconButton(
                iconSize: 30,
                icon: Icon(icons.elementAt(i)),
                color: _bottomAppBarIconColor(i),
                onPressed: () => _animateToPage(i),
              ),
            );
          }
        }()),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _animateToPage(int page) {
    _pageController.animateToPage(page,
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200), curve: Curves.linear);
  }

  Color _bottomAppBarIconColor(int page) {
    return _currentPage == page ? Colors.white : Theme.of(context).accentColor;
  }
}
```